# C++ change char in string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, subscript-operator

if i want to change a single char in a string i can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string mystring = "Hello";
  mystring[0] = 'T';
  cout << mystring;
  return 0;
}
```

If i want to change i single char in a string using a different function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void changeStr(string* mystring);

int main() {
  string mystring = "Hello";
    changeStr(&mystring);
  cout << mystring;
  return 0;
}

void changeStr(string* mystring)
{
    mystring[0] = 'T';
}
```

Why isnt it working? The whole string gets changed to "T". Im new to programming and still got some problems with pointers / address. I know that a array of char (char[]) is a pointer to its first index. Does this apply to a string aswell? How can i fix it?

Comment: In c++ we prefer pass by reference instead of passing by pointer. I would write `void changeStr(string & mystring)`  instead of `void changeStr(string* mystring)`

Comment: In your function you have a pointer to a string, not a string, So you should change your code to dereference the pointer `(*mystring)[0] = 'T';`. Or, like the comment above, you could change your function to use a reference.

Comment: *I know that a array of char (char[]) is a pointer to its first index. Does this apply to a string aswell?* No it does not, a `std::string` is an object, not an array or a pointer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Thats a big problem for me atm. Im not sure when to pass by reference or by pointer and dont really understand the difference.

Comment: Typo.  The first character of `string* mystring` is `mystring[0][0]` or `(*mystring)[0]`.  You are assigning `'T'` to the **entire string**.

Comment: General guideline for choosing between pointer and reference is this: If your function always expects a valid object, use a reference. Otherwise, `nullptr` should be considered as a possible value and you should use a pointer.

Comment: @user12002570 Edit reverted. There is no [tag:operator-precedence] here, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @user207421 What? Almost any real c++ program(including this) has operator precedence. Operator precedence is one of the fundamental aspects of c++. You'll find it in most(if not all) c++ programs. For example, statements like `mystring[0] = 'T'` use operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is no sense to pass an object of the type `std::string` to the function through a pointer to the object. You could pass it by reference. So the function could look like

```
void changeStr(string &mystring)
{
    mystring[0] = 'T';
}
```

Correspondingly the function is called like

```
changeStr(mystring);
```

As for your problem then at first you need to dereference the pointer and only after that to apply the subscript operator

```
void changeStr(string* mystring)
{
    ( *mystring )[0] = 'T';
}
```

Alternatively you could write

```
void changeStr(string* mystring)
{
    mystring->operator []( 0 ) = 'T';
}
```

Pay attention to that the postfix subscript operator has a higher precedence than the dereferencing operator.

As for the statement in your demonstration program within the function

```
mystring[0] = 'T';
```

then actually it assigns the character `'T'` to the string using the assignment operator

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

instead of assigning only the first character of the string.

That is after this statement the string will be equal to `"T"`.

It is the same if in `main` to write

```
mystring = 'T';
```

The expressions `*mystring` and `mystring[0]` where `mystring` has the pointer type `std::string *` are equivalent. So within the function you could even write

```
mystring[0][0] = 'T';
```

instead of

```
( *mystring )[0] = 'T';
```

Though as I pointed to early it is much better to pass the string by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I tried "( *mystring )[0] = 'T';" without the brackets and got a compiler error. Why are does needed in order to work? What does it change?

Comment: @Bele The subscript operator has a higher precedence than teh dereferencing operator but you need at first to apply teh dereferncing operator.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pass the pointer. Simply pass it by reference(reference will update the value) if you pass it by pointer then return the string instead of void..
better option .. pass it by reference

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;
 void changeStr(string &mystring);

 int main() {
 string mystring = "Hello";
  changeStr(mystring);
 cout << mystring;
 return 0;
}

void changeStr(string &mystring)
{
  mystring[0] = 'T';
}
```